# Alias Loop in csh

Tags: alias, echo, csh, df

Why is there an Alias loop error created here:

```
alias df 'printf "\n"; df -hP | column -t'
```

But not here:

```
alias df 'df -hP | column -t'
```

I realize I could call the alias something else and still have it work, however, I'm trying to understand the underlying operation.

Comment: I don't use csh, but it's possible that it assumes if the first command in the alias is the same as the name of the alias, it should use the non-alias, but otherwise it calls the alias.

Comment: You can work around that by using the full path, `/bin/df`

Comment: @Kevin I find that the only thing csh seems to be better than bash in is the alias syntax, mainly for formatting because it allows whitespace; that, and the fact that I don't have to create a function to open a program in the background (eg `e () { emacs $1 & }`)

Comment: You know you don't have to have the `&` in a function, right? You can just run `command &` straight from the command line.

Comment: @Kevin: submit it as an answer and I'll select it, but I'm still unsure why.  The other weird thing is that the whole reason I was putting a newline in there is the terminal was putting the column headings at a new prompt (the headings weren't lined with the columns), for some reason it's gone back to working as it should ... very odd

Comment: @Kevin I wanted to alias it to a shorter keystroke (in that case 1 letter), so I did have to wrap it in a function.  I'm guessing I could also have put a symlink in the bin dir, but the rc file is a more central place to manage aliases

Comment: Oh I see what you were getting at with the `&` on the command line.  I know that, but many of my aliases are created just to run the programs in the background, to free up the command prompt - I get tired of repeatedly typing `&`, so I create aliases for the programs.  I think my resource file would be significantly shorter if there were a way to set certain programs to run in the background by default.

Comment: Another workaround: `alias df 'printf "\n"; \df -hP | column -t'`

Comment: @KeithThompson 's answer is more correct because it doesn't require the full path which makes it more portable and stable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that when the alias name is also the first command, it's not interpreted as an alias, but beyond that it is.  This can be worked around with the absolute path:

```
alias df 'printf "\n"; /bin/df -hP | column -t'
```

Or, as a Keith pointed out in a comment and answer, `\` prevents alias expansion:

```
alias df 'printf "\n"; \df -hP | column -t'
```

Answer (score 6):

This is explained in the tcsh man page (I suspect you're using tcsh, not csh); see the third quoted paragraph.

> The shell maintains a list of aliases which can be set, unset and 
>   printed by the *alias* and *unalias* commands.  After a command  line
>   is parsed into simple commands (see **Commands**) the first  word of
>   each command, left-to-right, is checked to see if it has an alias. If
>   so, the first word is replaced by the alias. If the alias contains a
>   history reference, it undergoes **History substitution** (q.v.) as
>   though the original command were the previous input line. If the alias
>   does not contain a history reference, the argument list is left
>   untouched.
>
> Thus if the alias for `ls' were `ls -l' the command `ls /usr' would
>   become `ls -l /usr', the argument list here being undisturbed.
>   If the alias for `lookup' were `grep !^ /etc/passwd' then `lookup
>   bill' would become `grep bill /etc/passwd'. Aliases can be used to
>   introduce parser metasyntax. For example, `alias print 'pr !* |
>   lpr'' defines a ``command'' (`print') which pr(1)s its arguments to
>   the line printer.
>
> Alias substitution is repeated until the first word of the command has
>   no alias. If an alias substitution does not change the first word (as
>   in the previous example) it is flagged to prevent a loop. Other loops
>   are detected and cause an error.

A good workaround is to precede a command with a `\` character to inhibit alias expansion:

```
alias df 'printf "\n"; \df -hP | column -t'
```

Comment: The rule is the same in plain csh, and the same workaround works.

Comment: I have to check, but I'm pretty sure it's csh (old setup)